# Unknown Horizontal Scroll Bar Appears in Portrait Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, portrait

I am developing a webpage to be installed in a portrait tv screen. There will be no internet connection need to load this page. Directly I can install the HTML file to the device. You can see the developed webpage here: http://optionscreen.oriad.lk/Option_Screen_2.html  When this page is loaded through a web browser it works fine. When I install the HTML file to the device it displays a vertical scroll bar.

Just go through this video to understand what is my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ni9BhvJizOc

The portrait screen size is 1080 * 1920

Here is my Html code:

```js
        function buttonClickBooth(button, close) {
          var command = (close ? 'about:blank?arg="close": true, "bCmd": ' : 'about:blank?arg="bCmd": ');
          if (button.getAttribute("boothCommand"))
            window.location = command + button.getAttribute("boothCommand");
        }

        function buttonClickDevice(button) {
          if (button.getAttribute("deviceCommand"))
            window.location = 'about:blank?arg="dCmd": ' + button.getAttribute("deviceCommand");
        }
```

```css
  body,
        html {
          background: #000;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        #vid {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        #vid video {
          max-height: 100%;
          max-width: 100%;
          position: fixed;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        .gif {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 99;
          /*border: 3px solid red;*/
          height: 30%;
          width: 250px;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
        
        .gif.color {
          top: 5%;
        }
        
        .gif.bw {
          bottom: 18%;
        }
        
        button {
          cursor: pointer;
          background: transparent;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          border: 0px solid #fff;
        }
        
        @media (max-height:700px) {
          .gif.bw {
            bottom: 15%;
          }
          .gif.color {
            top: 0%;
          }
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
        <div id="vid" class="video touch">
          <video autoplay muted loop id="myvideo">
              <source src="Option Screen 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="Option Screen 2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
              Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="gif-color" class="gif color">
          <button boothCommand='"Color + Start"' onclick="buttonClickBooth(this, true)">
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="gif-bw" class="gif bw">
          <button boothCommand='"Grayscale + Start"' onclick="buttonClickBooth(this, true)">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```